# How to validate Form in React by pressing submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i am learning React and working on my pet-project. So, i have a form with custom input components and I want to validate them only when the user clicks on the button, but I don't know how. Full input check is whether the form is not empty and filled out correctly. I tried to create a model for subscribing components to the button click event, but when the form was filled correctly, the states were updated not after 1, but after 2 clicks, and I don't know why.

[Screen of form in browser:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH9lF.png)

Code of Form component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormBox } from '../FormBox';
import styles from './checkoutpage.module.scss'

export function CheckoutPage() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.formContainer}>
        <h2>checkout</h2>
          <legend>Contact info</legend>
          <FormBox
            type='email'
            placeholder='Email address'
            errorMessage='Enter a valid email address'
          />
          <legend>Shipping info</legend>
          <FormBox
            type='name'
            placeholder='Name'
          />
          <FormBox
            type='text'
            placeholder='Streer address'
          />
          <FormBox
            type='text'
            placeholder='Apt / Suite / Other (optional)'
          />
          <div className={styles.divideBox}>
            <FormBox
              type='text'
              placeholder='City'
            />
            <FormBox
              type='text'
              placeholder='Province'
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.divideBox}>
            <FormBox
              type='text'
              placeholder='Postal Code'
            />
            <FormBox
              type='text'
              placeholder='Country'
            />
          </div>
          <FormBox
            type='text'
            placeholder='Phone Number'
          />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code of Input component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./formbox.module.scss";

interface IFormBox {
  type: string;
  placeholder: string;
  errorMessage?: string;
}

export function FormBox({ type, placeholder, errorMessage }: IFormBox) {
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(true);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const checkValidityChange = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      setValid(ref.current.checkValidity());
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      if (valid && ref.current.value !== "") {
        ref.current.style.backgroundColor = "#e8f0fe";
      }
      else {
        ref.current.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }
    }
  }, [valid])

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <input 
        ref={ref}
        onChange={checkValidityChange}
        name="formInput" type={type}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onBlur={() => {if (ref.current && ref.current.value === "") ref.current.style.backgroundColor = "white";}}
      />

      {!valid && errorMessage && (
        <span>{'* '.concat(errorMessage)}</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Method i tried to use:

Form component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { FormBox } from '../FormBox';
import styles from './checkoutpage.module.scss'

export function CheckoutPage() {
  const [formValidity, setFormValidity] = useState(false);

  const [emailValidity, setEmailValidity] = useState(false);
  const [nameValidity, setNameValidity] = useState(false);
  const [addressValidity, setAddressValidity] = useState(false);
  const [aptValidity, setAptValidity] = useState(false);
  const [cityCalidity, setCityValidity] = useState(false);
  const [provinceValidity, setProvinceValidity] = useState(false);
  const [codeValidity, setCodeValidity] = useState(false);
  const [countryValidity, setCountryValidity] = useState(false);
  const [phoneValidity, setPhoneValidity] = useState(false);

  const refButton = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);

  function subscrition (event: MouseEvent, setValidity: (v: boolean) => void, setValidityValue: boolean) {
    if (event.target === refButton.current) {
      setValidity(setValidityValue);
    }
  }

  const getValidity = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const result = emailValidity && nameValidity && addressValidity && aptValidity && cityCalidity && provinceValidity && codeValidity && countryValidity && phoneValidity

    setFormValidity(result)
    console.log(formValidity)
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <form className={styles.formContainer}>
        <h2>checkout</h2>
          <legend>Contact info</legend>
          <FormBox
            subscrition={subscrition}
            type='email'
            placeholder='Email address'
            errorMessage='Enter a valid email address'
            setFullValidity={setEmailValidity}
          />
          <legend>Shipping info</legend>
          <FormBox
            subscrition={subscrition}
            type='name'
            placeholder='Name'
            setFullValidity={setNameValidity}
          />
          <FormBox
            subscrition={subscrition}
            type='text'
            placeholder='Streer address'
            setFullValidity={setAddressValidity}
          />
          <FormBox
            subscrition={subscrition}
            type='text'
            placeholder='Apt / Suite / Other (optional)'
            setFullValidity={setAptValidity}
          />
          <div className={styles.divideBox}>
            <FormBox
              subscrition={subscrition}
              type='text'
              placeholder='City'
              setFullValidity={setCityValidity}
            />
            <FormBox
              subscrition={subscrition}
              type='text'
              placeholder='Province'
              setFullValidity={setProvinceValidity}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.divideBox}>
            <FormBox
              subscrition={subscrition}
              type='text'
              placeholder='Postal Code'
              setFullValidity={setCodeValidity}
            />
            <FormBox
              subscrition={subscrition}
              type='text'
              placeholder='Country'
              setFullValidity={setCountryValidity}
            />
          </div>
          <FormBox
            subscrition={subscrition}
            type='text'
            placeholder='Phone Number'
            setFullValidity={setPhoneValidity}
          />
          <button ref={refButton} onClick={getValidity} type="submit" className={styles.btn}>Place Your Order</button>
          {formValidity && (
            <span style={{backgroundColor: "green"}}>Form is valid</span>
          )}
          {!formValidity && (
            <span style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>Form is invalid</span>
          )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Input component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./formbox.module.scss";

interface IFormBox {
  type: string;
  placeholder: string;
  errorMessage?: string;
  setFullValidity: (v: boolean) => void;
  subscrition: (event: MouseEvent, setValidity: (v: boolean) => void, setValidityValue: boolean) => void;
}

export function FormBox({ type, placeholder, errorMessage, setFullValidity, subscrition }: IFormBox) {
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(true);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const checkValidityChange = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      setValid(ref.current.checkValidity());
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      // @ts-ignore
      document.addEventListener('click', (event: MouseEvent) => {subscrition(event, setFullValidity, valid && (ref.current.value !== ""))})
    }
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      if (valid && ref.current.value !== "") {
        ref.current.style.backgroundColor = "#e8f0fe";
      } else {
        ref.current.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }
    }
  }, [valid])

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <input 
        ref={ref}
        onChange={checkValidityChange}
        name="formInput" type={type}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onBlur={() => {
          if (ref.current && ref.current.value === "") {
            ref.current.style.backgroundColor = "white";
          }
        }}
      />

      {!valid && errorMessage && (
        <span>{'* '.concat(errorMessage)}</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any advice on how to improve the code will be very warmly welcomed. Thanks for reading, and sorry if i waste your time.

Comment: You mean your validation is working fine but you are concern about the last line in question `the states were updated not after 1, but after 2 clicks, and I don't know why.` right?

Comment: Yes, that's too, but I really don't like the way I did it and would like to get information about a more correct way.

Comment: there are many ways to do the validation. it depends on your choice which way you will follow

Comment: I want to collect information about component states when a button is clicked. The components themselves must determine the value of the state only when the user clicks the button, because this states is needed only for this. That's the main problem. Can you please tell me what methods I can use at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this example to validate input fields. Here input reference is used like `ref` to validate data.

**WORKING DEMO**

[image: Edit #SO-material-onclick-edit]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./style.css";

function validate(name, email, password) {
  // we are going to store errors for all fields
  // in a signle array
  const errors = [];

  if (name.length === 0) {
    errors.push("Name can't be empty");
  }

  if (email.length < 5) {
    errors.push("Email should be at least 5 charcters long");
  }
  if (email.split("").filter(x => x === "@").length !== 1) {
    errors.push("Email should contain a @");
  }
  if (email.indexOf(".") === -1) {
    errors.push("Email should contain at least one dot");
  }

  if (password.length < 6) {
    errors.push("Password should be at least 6 characters long");
  }

  return errors;
}

class SignUpForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      errors: []
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this._nameInput).value;
    const email = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this._emailInput).value;
    const password = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this._passwordInput).value;

    const errors = validate(name, email, password);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      this.setState({ errors });
      return;
    }

    // submit the data...
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        {errors.map(error => (
          <p key={error}>Error: {error}</p>
        ))}
        <input
          ref={nameInput => (this._nameInput = nameInput)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
        />
        <input
          ref={emailInput => (this._emailInput = emailInput)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Email"
        />
        <input
          ref={passwordInput => (this._passwordInput = passwordInput)}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<SignUpForm />, rootElement);
```

[More Details](https://goshacmd.com/submit-time-validation-react/)